# Dynamically replotting every tick

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to plot two turtle variables against each other in a scatterplot. I want this plot to update continuously, and erase the points from previous steps. I.e. I want one point to move to represent the variable values for one turtle throughout its lifetime, disappearing when it dies and these values equal zero.

This is my code for the pen update commands (isspecials is my turtle agentset)

```
ask isspecials [plotxy r invader-stride]
```

I tried adding

```
reset-plot-pens
```

to the end of it, but then nothing appears on the plot. I think it's almost as if I have to create a new pen for each turtle, but I can't tell. I'm really new to this, so if anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Can you share what you have so far so that it can be run and examined? We need data and code.

Comment: My entire code is pretty long and I can't really post it, but the code for the model as a whole isn't my issue, it's just the code for the plot, which is exactly what's shown above. Just take r and invader-stride to be any two dynamic variables, and I'm trying to basically show a new plot at each step that has one dot per turtle with one (r, invader-stride) point.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried adding
>
> ```
> reset-plot-pens
> ```
>
> to the end of it

Adding [`plot-pen-reset`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plot-pen-reset) is the right idea! However, you need to add it *before* your plotting command.

The [`plot-pen-reset`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plot-pen-reset) primitive erases everything that the plot pen has drawn. If you call it right after you plot, you don't get a change to see anything! Calling it just before plotting new stuff will ensure that the stuff you plotted in the previous tick has plenty of time to be seen.

Here is what you plot pen definition should look like:

[image]